# Move to FCM Legacy HTTP API

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=11042019a&1572897862

It is written as

> The Apple Push Notification service (APNs) will no longer support the
>   legacy binary protocol as of November 2020.

in this article.

Does **"legacy binary protocol"** here mean **"FCM Legacy HTTP API"**?

I am currently using Legacy HTTP API.
In that case, will it not be possible to push on iOS unless you move from Legacy HTTP API to HTTP V1 API?